# preg_replace_callback strange behaviour

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I can't understand why preg_replace_callback handle pattern like this

```
    $article = "{{test1}} {{test2}}";

    $article = preg_replace_callback('{{(.*?)}}', 'handlePattern', $article);

    function handlePattern($matches) {
        echo "matches = " . print_r($matches, true);

    }
```

And it prints this result

```
    matches = Array
(
    [0] => {{test1}
    [1] => {test1
)
matches = Array
(
    [0] => {{test2}
    [1] => {test2
)
```

But I expect that it have to be like this

```
matches = Array
(
    [0] => {{test1}}
    [1] => test1
)
matches = Array
(
    [0] => {{test2}}
    [1] => test2
)
```

How can I get the content inside {{ }}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following expression the outer curly braces are interpreted as regular expression [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

`'{{(.*?)}}'`

You could use any delimiter actually. For instance, the following has the same effect:

`'/{(.*?)}/'`

So you should use delimiters in your expression, e.g.:

`'/{{(.*?)}}/'`

Also, you should quote the curly braces, because in certain sequences they can be interpreted as special regular expression characters:

```
'/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/'
```

An escaped version of a character for specific delimiter can be obtained by means of [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) function:

```
echo preg_quote('{', '/'); // \{
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using regular expression search, which requires you to declare pattern with [PCRE syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Your pattern `'{{(.*?)}}'` has `{` as beginning and `}`. PCRE treats them as the pattern beginning and end. Hence they are ignored from the pattern to match. You need to quote the pattern with additional quote character to make it work.

For example,

```
function handlePattern($matches) {
   echo "matches = " . print_r($matches, true);
}

$article = "{{test1}} {{test2}}";
$article = preg_replace_callback('/{{(.*?)}}/', 'handlePattern', $article);
```

Notice I've changed `'{{(.*?)}}'` to `'/{{(.*?)}}/'`.

The results:

```
matches = Array
(
    [0] => {{test1}}
    [1] => test1
)
matches = Array
(
    [0] => {{test2}}
    [1] => test2
)
```